# Не работает gulp watch

Tags: javascript, gulp

Не запускается таск watch, сервер стартует, а после него ничего.
В чем проблема и как исправить?

```
[22:03:35] Finished 'clean' after 13 ms
[22:03:36] Starting 'pages'...
[22:03:36] Starting 'sass'...
[22:03:36] Finished 'pages' after 470 ms
[22:03:36] Finished 'sass' after 471 ms
[22:03:36] Starting 'server'...
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
```

gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
// var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var browser = require('browser-sync').create();
var panini = require('panini');
var rimraf = require('rimraf');

gulp.task('server', function () {
  browser.init({
    server: "dist",
    port: 8080,
    open: true,
    notify: false
  });
});

gulp.task('reload', function(done) {
  browser.reload();
  done();
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/assets/scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css/'))
    .pipe(browser.reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('pages', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/pages/**/*.html')
    .pipe(panini({
      root: 'src/pages/',
      layouts: 'src/layouts/',
      partials: 'src/partials/',
      data: 'src/data/',
      helpers: 'src/helpers/'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(browser.reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('resetPages', function(done) {
  panini.refresh();
  done();
});

gulp.task('clean', function(done) {
  rimraf('dist', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('src/assets/scss/**/*', gulp.series('sass', browser.reload));
  gulp.watch('src/pages/**/*.html', gulp.series('pages', 'refresh', browser.reload));
  gulp.watch('src/{layouts,partials}/**/*.html', gulp.series('resetPages', 'pages', browser.reload));
});

gulp.task('default',
  gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('pages', 'sass'),'server','watch'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил добавив аргумент `done` и вызов данного метода `done()` в таске `server`.

```
gulp.task('server', function (done) {
  browser.init({
    server: "dist",
    port: 8080,
    open: true,
    notify: false
  });
  done();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

может поменять на

```
gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('pages', 'sass', 'server','watch'));
```